# QlikView: Showing Bars in Different Colors

Tags: qlikview

I have made the following chart:
[image]

When a user makes a selection, is it possible to display the resulting bars in different colors than the ones displayed on the photo?
For example, now the bars are displayed in grey, dark blue, and light blue colors. When a user selects Q1, the 3 bars should be displayed in following collors: Red, Yellow, Green etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. from the "Colors" Tab you can set each color to use a calc
   [image]
2. from the "Expressions" Tab, if you click the "+" left to the expression, you will see a "background Color" - there you can also enter any calc. i.e :

   if(Quarter='Q1', rgb(100,100,100),rgb(200,200,200))...

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have defined in the dimensions tab one dimension 'Quarter' and a drill down group which contains 'Scenario' and 'Region'. The chart should display the default colors, except when a user drills down to region. Can you pelase help me with the calculated expression that does that?

Comment: btw, the color Area is for the Frame Background. Right? I need to change Bar colors. Where can I find that?

Comment: in a bar chart it is the bar color

Comment: just use: if(GetCurrentField(CycleFieldName)='Region',color1,color2)

Comment: the color has changed - but the color of the background, not the color of the bars. Where in the 'Color' tab can I enter the calculated expression that effects bars?

Comment: you're talking about the "frame background" ... I'm saying just click on the color itself (in the "Data Apperance") and it will show you what I posted above